# Cant set the background color of a QTableWidgetItem?

Tags: qt, qt5, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem, qcolor

I am trying to set the background color of a QTableWidgetItem, but it doenst work?
When I try to change the textcolor, it works without any problems..

Code:

```
void myWin::myFunction(int count, QVector<QColor> sampleInfoColor, QVector<QStringList> info)
{
    ...
    sampleTable->setRowCount(count + 1);
    QFont nameFont;
    nameFont.setBold(true);
    ...
    for(int i=0; i<count; i++)
    {
        ...
        QTableWidgetItem *name = new QTableWidgetItem("Text");
        name->setFont(nameFont);
        sampleTable->setItem(i+1, 0, name);
        name->setBackground(sampleInfoColor[i]);
        ...
    }
}
```

I also tried this, but it didnt work too..:

```
sampleTable.item(nRow, nCol)->setBackground(QColor);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: The background-color of  the QTableWidgetItem "name" doesnt change..

Comment: When I qDebug the sampleInfoColor[i], I get this: QColor(ARGB 1, 0, 0, 1).

Comment: Oh guys, I found my problem.....in the constructor of my class I've set the stylesheet for the QTableWidget, without it works perfect...thats embarassing..

Answer (score 1):

Can you give this a try:

```
name->setBackground( QBrush( sampleInfoColor[i] ) );
```

Comment: Doesnt work...also tried this with "sampleTable->item(row,col).setBackground(....);", but it doesn't work too...

Answer (score -1):

Put Label into tableWidget, modify the color of Label, label is QLabel

```
tableWidget->setItem(row, col, new QTableWidgetItem);
tableWidget->setCellWidget(row, col++, label);
label->setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 229, 0);");
```